# ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to update my Android project.

I initially got this error:

> ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
>   Possible causes:
>   The project 'xxx' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project

So I tried this in my app's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.

What to do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the current versions of the Android `Gradle` plugin are not added to `Maven Central`, but they are present on `jcenter`. Add `jcenter()` to your list of repositories and `Gradle` should find version

```
repositories {
    ....
    jcenter()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23049765)